# Gradle exec PATH in Android Studio doesn't match command line

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm running a Gradle script that needs to `exec` a few commands. (In my example, it's `node`.)

In my Terminal, `node` is on my `PATH`, so I can type `node --version` and it just works. My Gradle script works fine on the command line.

But when I try to run the Gradle build in Android Studio, it says:

```
> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'node''
Cause: error=2, No such file or directory
```

Unfortunately, the way this script runs on various machines, I can't be sure what the path to `node` will be; I need to use the `PATH` environment from the user's machine. (On macOS, `node` might be in `/usr/local/bin` or `/opt/homebrew/bin` or `~/n/bin` or something else entirely.)

How do I make this work?

EDIT: To clarify, our developers will launch Android Studio via the OS launcher, e.g. by double-clicking it in Finder on macOS, or from the Start menu in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

My hunch would be that the `PATH` in Android Studio depends on how Android Studio is started. If I start it from a Linux shell, then it uses the same `PATH` which is set in that shell. If you use an OS-specific launcher, then I suppose the `PATH` depends on what this launcher used – which may be different from the one that you set explicitly/implicitly for your shell (e.g., in a `~/.bashrc` file).

I doubt that you can get this to work reliably without manually making sure on all user machines that the `PATH` is always set correctly for Android Studio – or that you manually make sure that all `node` installations end up on the “most system-wide” `PATH` that is available for each OS installation.

Comment: I updated my question. I am indeed launching Android Studio from Finder in macOS, and something similar seems to be wrong when I try Android Studio on Windows, launched via the Start menu.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that’d be the case. As said, I doubt that this can be solved generically without manually making sure on each system that `node` is on the “most system-wide” `PATH`. That’s how environment variables work, it’s not specific to Android Studio or Gradle.